routing stuck (stopped working) after a few clicks if a router is declared in child component
on Angular version 18.0.0
//package.json
"@angular/animations": "^18.0.0",
"@angular/common": "^18.0.0",
"@angular/compiler": "^18.0.0",
"@angular/core": "^18.0.0",

my routing initially seems to work fine
//app.config.ts
import { provideRouter } from '@angular/router';
import { provideNoopAnimations } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { routes } from './app.routes';

export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [provideZoneChangeDetection({ eventCoalescing: true }), 
provideRouter(routes), provideNoopAnimations()]
};

//app.routes.ts
export const routes: Routes = [
    {
      path: 'staff',
      component: StaffComponent,
      title: 'Home details',
      children: StaffRoutes
    },
];

//staff/staff.routes.ts
export const StaffRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: 'new', component: StaffDetailComponent },
    { path: 'view/:id', component: StaffDetailComponent },
    { path: 'list', component: StaffListComponent },
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'list', pathMatch: 'full' },
]

//top-navitgation.component.ts
export class TopNavigationComponent {
  items: MenuItem[] | undefined;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.items = [
        {
            label: 'Home',
            route: '/',
        },
        {
            label: 'Staff',
            route: 'staff',
        },
    ];
}

//staff-sub-menu.component.ts
export class StaffSubMenuComponent {
  items: MenuItem[] | undefined;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.items = [
        {
            label: 'Functions',
            items: [

                {
                    label: 'View staffs',
                    icon: 'pi pi-list',
                    route: 'list'
                },
                {
                    label: 'New Staff',
                    route: 'new'
                },
            ]
        }
    ];
} 
}

//app.component.html
<main>
  <p-toast/>
  <nav><app-top-navigation></app-top-navigation></nav>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</main>

//staff.component.html
<router-outlet></router-outlet>

all routing works fine (clicks the links navigate to the components without issue) right up until I add anything that is Router related into the "child" component StaffDetailComponent
//staff-detail-component.ts
import { Router } from '@angular/router'; //not useful if I cannot use router

@Component({
   providers: [Router], //not useful if I cannot use router
})

export class StaffDetailComponent {
  //router: Router; //because router cannot be initialized (stuck) it cannot be declared
  
  staffService: StaffService = inject(StaffService);

  //cannot do this, it will cause routing to be stuck
  constructor(private messageService: MessageService, private router : Router) {
  }

  constructor(private messageService: MessageService, private injector: Injector) {
    //injecting also stucks the routing
    //this.router = this.injector.get(Router); 
    doStuff();
  }

  doStuff(): void {
    //which means I don't get to do this
    //this.router.navigate(['staff/list']);
  }
}

either when I try to declare a router in the component constructor, or inject a router, after I nagivated through the staffDetail component, it gets stuck, meaning which ever link I click, it stays on same page without navigating. When mouse over in the browser, the links still shows the correct addresses from the routes.ts

Did I miss any concept of route / provideRoute?
is the multi-layered router-outlet causing this? Did I use the wrong design / got it totally wrong?
If I am trying to navigate to somewhere else like after pressing a button to save things in doStuff(), is this.router.navigate(['staff/list']); the correct call or is there some other routing / navigation pattern I should use?


The imports step is only needed when you want to use the directives like routerLink and routerLinkActive, you can add either RouterModule or RouterLink separately. Since you are just using the router service, there is no need for importing them.
You have to use inject to use the Router, as shown below. We can also use relativeTo: this.route, which means, the navigation will happen starting from the root element being the current element where we navigate.
Another option is /staff which will always navigate from the root path of the application /, I think you might prefer this method.
//staff-detail-component.ts
import { Router } from '@angular/router'; //not useful if I cannot use router
@Component({
   providers: [],
})
export class StaffDetailComponent {
  // router: Router = inject(Router);   
  staffService: StaffService = inject(StaffService);

  constructor(
    private messageService: MessageService, 
    private router : Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
  ) { }

  doStuff(): void {
    //which means I don't get to do this
    this.router.navigate(['/staff/list']); // <- absolute routing
    // this.router.navigate(['../../list'], { // <- relative routing
    //   relativeTo: this.route
    // });
  }
}


Thanks, it worked by just injecting right under export class, did not need to private router : Router in constructor

@JimmyChiKinChau Both method will work. the problem, was the Router in the imports array of the component
